# With jQuery is it faster to assign a variable or use $(this) for single use?

Tags: jquery, performance, semantics

My question is driven by curiosity, and I appreciate any performance difference is liable to be minuscule.

I was recently looking at producing some hover effects for an image map. As with most things someone else had suggested a method with jQuery. Below was the suggest code

```
$('#borders area').each(function(){
    var mapRegion = $(this).attr('class');
    $(this).hover(
        function(){
            $('#regions').addClass(mapRegion).show();
        },
        function(){
            $('#regions').hide().removeClass(mapRegion);
    });
});
```

This obviously works fine where `<div id="regions">` is positioned absolutely above a base `<img>` and the a further blank transparent `<img>` is placed above this for `<map id="borders">`.

I did wonder however if it made more sense (slightly less code) to do the following with the jQuery

```
$('#borders area').each(function(){
    $(this).hover(
        function(){
            $('#regions').removeClass().addClass($(this).attr('class')).show();
        },
        function(){
            $('#regions').hide();
    });
});
```

Would this be faster as no variable is set? Does removeClass() work faster without a parameter supplied? I suppose I would also be interested to know which semantically is considered better.

Comment: Since you're looking to test the speed of these two, I'd suggest using jsperf.  I've created an example one here: http://jsperf.com/jquery-this-test

Comment: Testing the speed of a simple event handler doesn't really tell you much, other than the fact that an event handler like this can be bound around 40k times every second. Added my own solution as well -> http://jsperf.com/jquery-this-test/2

Comment: @MSost - Thanks for the info you've both provided. Very useful, was not aware of jsperf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion what would make more sense is probably :

```
$('#borders area').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'mouseenter') {
        $('#regions').removeClass().addClass(this.className).show();
    }else{
        $('#regions').hide();
    }
});
```

As that avoids the uneccessary loop and `hover()` wrapping of mouseenter/mouseleave, and gets the classname from the native property.

As for speed, you'll never notice the difference.

Comment: Thanks for your suggested code here, and also the comment above with the jsperf example. I'd have never considered doing it this way, so learnt something useful. Maybe you can edit your question to include your jsperf link as others would no doubt find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

> Would this be faster as no variable is set? Does removeClass() work
>   faster without a parameter supplied?

Since you are concerned with knowing what the difference in performance is from an academic perspective (since there will probably never, ever be a perceptible one), I would suggest doing some benchmarking of your own.

A useful online tool for that: http://jsperf.com/